# ggplot2 control number of panels per row when using facet?

Tags: r, ggplot2, panel, facet

Is it possible to control the number of panels per row in a ggplot? I can only get an equal number of panels on each row as in the example plot below.
[image: Example plot]

For example I have data that is naturally grouped into 22 blocks by 'Marker' which in turn are organised by 'Dye' (see example code and data below). In this example I would like to arrange the panels in 4 rows with 5, 6, 6, and 5 panels respectively on each row (as in the picture at the end, but the 22 blocks can be equally wide).

Example code:

```
    df$Type <- factor(round(df$Type, 2))
    df$Allele <- factor(df$Allele)
    gp <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x = "Allele", y = "Ratio", colour = "Type")) 
    gp <- gp + geom_point(alpha = 0.8, position = position_jitter(width = 0.1))
    gp <- gp + facet_grid(Dye ~ Marker) + facet_wrap(~Marker, ncol = 5, drop = FALSE, scales = "free_x")
    gp <- gp + guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
    gp <- gp + labs(title = "Stutter ratios")
    print(gp)
```

Example data:

```
    Marker  Allele  Ratio   Type    Dye
    DYS576  18  0.116157205 -1  B
    DYS389 I    14  0.043252595 -1  B
    DYS448  19  0.018236074 -1  B
    DYS389 II   31  0.102169982 -1  B
    DYS19   14  0.058139535 -1  B
    DYS19   14  0.078224101 -0.2    B
    DYS391  10  0.090035245 -1  G
    DYS481  22  0.013492063 -2  G
    DYS481  22  0.179365079 -1  G
    DYS549  13  0.0625  -1  G
    DYS533  12  0.07564495  -1  G
    DYS437  14  0.04757085  -1  G
    DYS570  17  0.071079867 -1  Y
    DYS570  17  0.007420426 1   Y
    DYS635  21  0.192561983 -1  Y
    DYS390  24  0.073079325 -1  Y
    DYS439  12  0.084817642 -1  Y
    DYS392  13  0.125965997 -1  Y
    DYS393  13  0.009672831 -2  R
    DYS393  13  0.079374111 -1  R
    DYS393  13  0.013371266 1   R
    DYS458  17  0.126099707 -1  R
    DYS385  13  0.059782609 -1  R
    DYS385  16  0.092356688 -1  R
    DYS456  17  0.12    -1  R
    YGATAH4 11  0.07203718  -1  R
    DYS576  18  0.094989562 -1  B
    DYS389 I    14  0.044955045 -1  B
    DYS448  19  0.017171717 -1  B
    DYS389 II   31  0.124137931 -1  B
    DYS391  10  0.052903833 -1  G
    DYS481  22  0.198726115 -1  G
    DYS549  13  0.08853967  -1  G
    DYS533  12  0.106617647 -1  G
    DYS438  9   0.017562533 -1  G
    DYS570  17  0.006710002 -2  Y
    DYS570  17  0.076326274 -1  Y
    DYS570  17  0.007339065 1   Y
    DYS635  21  0.132272501 -1  Y
    DYS390  24  0.078853047 -1  Y
    DYS439  12  0.06980198  -1  Y
    DYS392  13  0.104508197 -1  Y
    DYS393  13  0.083853995 -1  R
    DYS393  13  0.014140085 1   R
    DYS458  17  0.094651285 -1  R
    DYS385  13  0.076977401 -1  R
    DYS385  13  0.076977401 -1  R
    DYS385  16  0.059866962 -1  R
    DYS385  16  0.059866962 -1  R
    DYS456  17  0.151162791 -1  R
    YGATAH4 11  0.09254902  -1  R
    DYS576  18  0.126856684 -1  B
    DYS389 I    14  0.052631579 -1  B
    DYS389 II   31  0.102253033 -1  B
    DYS19   14  0.056882821 -1  B
    DYS19   14  0.080773606 -0.2    B
    DYS391  10  0.053362122 -1  G
    DYS481  22  0.033595801 -2  G
    DYS481  22  0.164829396 -1  G
    DYS549  13  0.123548922 -1  G
    DYS533  12  0.06750174  -1  G
    DYS437  14  0.041118421 -1  G
    DYS570  17  0.097141001 -1  Y
    DYS570  17  0.010071475 1   Y
    DYS635  21  0.070416095 -1  Y
    DYS390  24  0.075715605 -1  Y
    DYS439  12  0.077648766 -1  Y
    DYS392  13  0.116974494 -1  Y
    DYS643  10  0.017945781 -1  Y
    DYS393  13  0.011755878 -2  R
    DYS393  13  0.121810905 -1  R
    DYS393  13  0.017008504 1   R
    DYS458  17  0.097028366 -1  R
    DYS385  13  0.083820663 -1  R
    DYS385  16  0.124661247 -1  R
    DYS456  17  0.11167002  -1  R
    DYS576  18  0.102416918 -1  B
    DYS448  19  0.021699819 -1  B
    DYS19   14  0.064239829 -0.2    B
    DYS391  10  0.054468085 -1  G
    DYS481  22  0.048726467 -2  G
    DYS481  22  0.182724252 -1  G
    DYS549  13  0.091326105 -1  G
    DYS533  12  0.074295474 -1  G
    DYS438  9   0.059535822 -1  G
    DYS437  14  0.044034091 -1  G
    DYS570  17  0.02547279  -2  Y
    DYS570  17  0.129293709 -1  Y
    DYS570  17  0.012350444 1   Y
    DYS635  21  0.09912927  -1  Y
    DYS390  24  0.086936937 -1  Y
    DYS439  12  0.060550459 -1  Y
    DYS392  13  0.149750416 -1  Y
    DYS393  13  0.08388521  -1  R
    DYS393  13  0.016188374 1   R
    DYS458  17  0.009228937 -2  R
    DYS458  17  0.092289372 -1  R
    DYS458  17  0.062816314 1   R
    DYS385  13  0.068504595 -1  R
    DYS385  16  0.077120823 -1  R
    DYS456  17  0.131855309 -1  R
    YGATAH4 11  0.070570571 -1  R
    DYS576  18  0.108604407 -1  B
    DYS389 I    14  0.053097345 -1  B
    DYS389 II   31  0.122986823 -1  B
    DYS19   14  0.044878049 -1  B
    DYS19   14  0.069268293 -0.2    B
    DYS391  10  0.057256368 -1  G
    DYS481  22  0.029480217 -2  G
    DYS481  22  0.171450737 -1  G
    DYS549  13  0.078275862 -1  G
    DYS533  12  0.062146893 -1  G
    DYS437  14  0.037869063 -1  G
    DYS570  17  0.0956807   -1  Y
    DYS570  17  0.021323127 1   Y
    DYS635  21  0.076858108 -1  Y
    DYS390  24  0.099143207 -1  Y
    DYS439  12  0.057610242 -1  Y
    DYS439  12  0.028449502 1   Y
    DYS392  13  0.101621622 -1  Y
    DYS393  13  0.012474012 -2  R
    DYS393  13  0.117463617 -1  R
    DYS393  13  0.01039501  1   R
    DYS458  17  0.081623347 -1  R
    DYS385  13  0.068003487 -1  R
    DYS385  16  0.066376496 -1  R
    DYS456  17  0.149382716 -1  R
```

[image: Example]

**Update:** Finally had some time to try to solve this issue. Based on DWin's answer and with the help of some examples found online I have manage to create a plot almost as I wish. However I need some more help to get it exactly as I want:

1) How can I make the panels equally wide (or tall) in each plot and still be able to put in titles and legends only in some plots.

2) How can I center the y title and the legend vertically across all plots.

3) Of course I want to use the same colour for the same types in the different panels, but I suppose that should be easy using ggplot. But any advice here is also welcome.

See attached code and image for my progress so far.

```
# Prepare data.
df$Marker <- factor(df$Marker, levels = c("DYS576", "DYS389 I", "DYS448", "DYS389 II", "DYS19",
                                          "DYS391", "DYS481", "DYS549", "DYS533", "DYS438", "DYS437",
                                          "DYS570", "DYS635", "DYS390", "DYS439", "DYS392",
                                          "DYS643", "DYS393", "DYS458", "DYS385", "DYS456", "YGATAH4" ))
df$Type <- factor(round(df$Type, 2))
df$Dye <- factor(df$Dye, levels = c("B", "G", "Y", "R"))
df$Allele <- factor(df$Allele)

# Get y max to use same scale.
yMax <- max(df$Ratio)

# Get dyes.
dyes <- levels(df$Dye)

# start new page
plot.new() 

# setup layout
gl <- grid.layout(nrow=length(dyes) , ncol=1)
# grid.show.layout(gl) # To inspect layout.

# Init layout
pushViewport(viewport(layout=gl))

# Loop over all dyes.
for(d in seq(along=dyes)){

  # Move to the next viewport
  pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col=1, layout.pos.row=d))

  # Create a plot for the current subset.  
  gp <- ggplot(subset(df, Dye==dyes[d]), aes_string(x = "Allele", y = "Ratio")) 
  gp <- gp + geom_point(aes_string(colour = "Type"), alpha = 0.8, position = position_jitter(width = 0.1))
  gp <- gp + facet_grid(Dye ~ Marker, scales="free_x")
  gp <- gp + ylim(0, yMax)

  # If first dye channel.
  if(d == 1){

    # Plot title only.
    gp <- gp + labs(title = "Stutter ratios")
    gp <- gp + theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())
    gp <- gp + theme(axis.title.y=element_blank())

    # Remove legends.
    gp <- gp + theme(legend.position="none")

  } else if(d == length(dyes)){ # If last dye channel.

    # No title but x and y labels.
    # Y label should ideally be centered vertically in final plot.
    gp <- gp + labs(title = element_blank())
    gp <- gp + labs(xlab = "Allele")
    gp <- gp + labs(xlab = "Ratio")

    # Not removing legend works but makes the last plot more compact (horizontally).
    # Can the panel height or width be fixed for all subplots?

    # 'bottom' is nicer (assuming I can't center it vertically in the final plot)
    # but makes the last dye channel very compact (vertically).
    # gp <- gp + theme(legend.position="bottom")

  } else {  # No titles, labels or legends.

    gp <- gp + labs(title = element_blank())
    gp <- gp + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
    gp <- gp + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
    gp <- gp + theme(legend.position="none")
  }

  # Print the ggplot graphics here
  print(gp, newpage = FALSE)

  # Done with this viewport
  popViewport(1)

}
```

[image: Plot using grid.layout]

**Update 2:** New try using gtable as suggesteb by baptiste. I can now produce the exact plot that I want. The only improvement in appearance I can think of is to reduce the horizontal space that the legend takes up. Happy for any suggestions on that. But I will not use more time to try and find out myself, the plot is close enough to perfect for me.

New code and plot below. The code can probably be cleaned a bit, so leave a comment if you have any tip.

```
# Prepare data.
df$Marker <- factor(df$Marker, levels = c("DYS576", "DYS389 I", "DYS448", "DYS389 II", "DYS19",
                                          "DYS391", "DYS481", "DYS549", "DYS533", "DYS438", "DYS437",
                                          "DYS570", "DYS635", "DYS390", "DYS439", "DYS392",
                                          "DYS643", "DYS393", "DYS458", "DYS385", "DYS456", "YGATAH4" ))
df$Type <- factor(round(df$Type, 2))
df$Dye <- factor(df$Dye, levels = c("B", "G", "Y", "R"))
df$Allele <- factor(df$Allele)

# Get y max to use same scale.
yMax <- max(df$Ratio)

# Get dyes.
dyes <- levels(df$Dye)
# Number of dyes.
noDyes <- length(dyes)
# Number of rows in table object.
noRows <- length(dyes) + 2

# Create table object.
g <- gtable(widths=unit(c(1,4,1),c("lines","null","null")),
            heights = unit(c(1,rep(1,noDyes),1), c("line",rep("null",noDyes), "line")))

# Add titles.
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, textGrob("Stutter ratios"), t=1,b=1,l=2,r=2)
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, textGrob("Allele"), t=noRows ,b=noRows ,l=2,r=2)
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, textGrob("Ratio", rot=90), t=1,b=noRows ,l=1,r=1)

# Create a plot for the entire dataset to extract the legend.
gp <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x = "Allele", y = "Ratio")) 
gp <- gp + geom_point(aes_string(colour = "Type"))
# Extract the legend.
guide <- gtable_filter(ggplotGrob(gp), pattern="guide")
# Add the legend to the table object.
g <- gtable_add_grob(g,guide , t=1,b=noRows,l=3,r=3)

# Loop over all dyes.
for(d in seq(along=dyes)){

  # Create a plot for the current subset.
  gp <- ggplot(subset(df, Dye==dyes[d]), aes_string(x = "Allele", y = "Ratio")) 
  gp <- gp + geom_point(aes_string(colour = "Type"), alpha = 0.8, position = position_jitter(width = 0.1))
  gp <- gp + scale_colour_discrete(drop = FALSE)
  gp <- gp + facet_grid(Dye ~ Marker, scales="free_x")
  gp <- gp + ylim(0, yMax)

  # Remove titles, axis labels and legend.
  gp <- gp + labs(title = element_blank())
  gp <- gp + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
  gp <- gp + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
  gp <- gp + theme(legend.position="none")

  # Add plot panel to table object.  
  g <- gtable_add_grob(g,ggplotGrob(gp), t=(d+1),b=(d+1),l=2,r=2)

}

# Plot.
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image: Plot using gtable]

Comment: currently the widths are allocated with 4 times more space for the panels than for the legend. You can either change this ratio by trial-and-error, or use `unit(1, "null")` for the panels, and `sum(guide$widths)` for the legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to place grobs is to use the gtable package,

```
library(gtable)
gtable_add_grobs <- gtable_add_grob #misleading name

g <- gtable(widths=unit(c(1,4,1),c("lines","null","null")),
            heights = unit(c(1,1,1,1), c("line","null","null", "line")))

lg <- list(textGrob("title"), 
           textGrob("xlab"),
           textGrob("ylab", rot=90),
           rectGrob(),
           rectGrob(),
           rectGrob())

pos <- data.frame(t=c(1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2),
                  b=c(1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3),
                  l=c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3),
                  r=c(3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3))

g <- with(pos, gtable_add_grobs(g, lg, t=t, l=l, b=b, r=r))
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

You can extract the legend of a ggplot with `gtable_filter(ggplotGrob(p), pattern="guide")`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I manage to get the plot as I wanted it. See update 2.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you will need to use viewports. This will allow you to specify the layouts separately for each row.

```
 library(grid)
 ?grid.layout
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the core problem of plotting unequal number of facets per row. But the result is not yet perfect. I would like the axis titles and legends not to affect the panels width and height. See my update.

Comment: Although it is probably possible to create the plot in update 2 using grid, baptiste provided a simpler solution. However, working with both grid and gtable is new to me...