# ggplot place facet between two rows of facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 9 plots with 3 time series in each plot, one of these plots contains only one curve and it's the reference plot which I would like to place in between the two rows that contain the other 8 plots. Is there an easy way to do so?
I use `facet_wrap(~density,nrow=2)` but I get one row with 5 and another with 4 plots. I am sure other people had this problem, is there an easy way around to organize the position of this reference plot, or do I have to create two separate plots and overlay them? Otherwise I might have to move this reference plot in all the other plots but it seems redundant information.

This is my current result, but as you can see it's not very well laid out.
[image]

Comment: I don't understand very well what you are trying to do, but it sounds to me that you need `gridExtra`

Comment: @SRivero I have added a screen shot to give you an idea

Comment: Not what you asked for but you could also consider adding the 'control' line as a background in the other facets, such as is shown here: https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/plotting-background-data-for-groups-with-ggplot2

Comment: I think the easiest way is make separate plots and put them together as in http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314058/ggplot2-control-number-of-panels-per-row-when-using-facet. Not sure if it is a duplicate

Comment: Can you provide the code _and_ data you used to produce this plot via copy and pasting and `dput(my_data)`?

Comment: @BLT that seems like a good solution, but my reference plot keeps getting drawn in a separate facet.

Comment: @user4050 ok, I hadn't tried it myself yet. Bummer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graphic you are looking for can be generated with gridArrange from the
[gridExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gridExtra) package.  Here is
an example using the `storms` data set from the
[dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dplyr).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)
data(storms, package = 'dplyr')
str(storms)

## Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    10010 obs. of  13 variables:
##  $ name       : chr  "Amy" "Amy" "Amy" "Amy" ...
##  $ year       : num  1975 1975 1975 1975 1975 ...
##  $ month      : num  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
##  $ day        : int  27 27 27 27 28 28 28 28 29 29 ...
##  $ hour       : num  0 6 12 18 0 6 12 18 0 6 ...
##  $ lat        : num  27.5 28.5 29.5 30.5 31.5 32.4 33.3 34 34.4 34 ...
##  $ long       : num  -79 -79 -79 -79 -78.8 -78.7 -78 -77 -75.8 -74.8 ...
##  $ status     : chr  "tropical depression" "tropical depression" "tropical depression" "tropical depression" ...
##  $ category   : Ord.factor w/ 7 levels "-1"<"0"<"1"<"2"<..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
##  $ wind       : int  25 25 25 25 25 25 25 30 35 40 ...
##  $ pressure   : int  1013 1013 1013 1013 1012 1012 1011 1006 1004 1002 ...
##  $ ts_diameter: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
##  $ hu_diameter: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Let's create two graphics. The first graphic will be only form `category == -1`
storms (this would be the control group in your question).  The second
graphic will be a facteted graphic for the `category > -1` storm

First, we'll build a generic ggplot object for the graphics.

```
graphic <-
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = long, y = lat, color = category) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap( ~ category) +
  scale_color_hue(breaks = levels(storms$category),
                  labels = levels(storms$category),
                  drop = FALSE)
```

Next we build the two graphics as needed.

```
g1 <- graphic %+% dplyr::filter(storms, category == -1) + theme(legend.position = "none")
g2 <- graphic %+% dplyr::filter(storms, category != -1)
```

`gridExtra::grid.arrange` can take a layout matrix where the numbers 1 and 2
denote the first and second graphics passed to the function.  (This works for
a lot more than just two graphics, by the way.)  By repeating the values of 1
and 2 in the matrix we can control the relative size of the two graphics in
the graphics device.

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(g1, g2,
                        layout_matrix = 
                          matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                                   1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                                   1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                                 byrow = TRUE, nrow = 3) 
                        )
```

[image]

Comment: That's not the intended use of layout_matrix. If you want to control the relative sizes, better do something like `grid.arrange(g1, g2, widths = c(3, 5))`. Also, in this particular case I would recommend `egg::ggarrange()`, which would align the two plots.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you could reformat your data with appropriate facetting variables to introduce a new row of reference panels

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(x=rep(1:10, 8), y = rnorm(80), 
                f=gl(8,10, ordered = TRUE))
d$f1 <- factor(d$f <= 4, labels=c(1,3))
d$f2 <- as.numeric(d$f) %% 4

d2 <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=0, f1 = 2)

ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=f)) + 
  geom_point(data=d2, colour="black") + 
  facet_grid(f1~f2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however that adds more plots, instead I am trying to optimize the real estate.

Comment: that's what I understood by "place between two rows of facets"